# Displaying divs inline when using hover

Tags: html, css

I am using html & css to display a colour version of a logo when you hover over the charcol version of a logo.

I want the logos to be displayed inline next to each other like:

x--x--x

x--x--x

but instead they are displaying like:

x

x

x

Can anyone help - i'm sure it must be something simple. V inexperienced with CSS/HTML.

HTML:

```
<div class="all-logos">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="charcol-logo"><img src=grey2.png></div>
    <div class="color-logo">
      <a href=http://www.bbc.co.uk><img src=color2.png></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="charcol-logo"><img src=grey1.png></div>
     <div class="color-logo">
      <a href=http://www.bbc.co.uk><img src=red1.png></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo:hover>.charcol-logo {
  display: none;
}

.logo:hover>.color-logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.color-logo {
  display: none;
}

.all-logos {
  width: 30%;
  border: black 1px solid;
}

.all-logos img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you're looking for with flex-box properties.

```
.all-logos {
  max-width: 30%;
  border: black 1px solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I could help.  Would you please mark this as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add following to your stylesheet..

```
.all-logos .logo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px; /* Only if you want space between elements */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you want?

```css
.logo:hover>.charcol-logo {
  display: none;
}

.logo:hover>.color-logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.color-logo {
  display: none;
}

.all-logos {
  width: 30%;
  border: black 1px solid;
}

.all-logos img {
  max-width:100%;
}

.all-logos .logo {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-logos">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="charcol-logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
    <div class="color-logo">
      <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="charcol-logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
    <div class="color-logo">
      <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```